# Exactly Half of a 3D Transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, homogeneous-spaces

I have a 3D homogeneous transformation matrix $T$ that defines the rotation and translation between two reference frames.

I want to find the transformation that when applied gives a new reference frame, which is exactly in the middle of these two reference frames and has half of total orientation between the two reference frames.

Basically, how to find the transformation, which is exactly half, both in terms of rotation and translation.

Can you anyone suggest how to proceed ahead ?

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a "square root" of the transformation; a transformation that, if applied twice, produces the full rotation+translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your transformation consists of a rotation by non-zero angle $\theta$ (about the origin), whose $3 \times 3$ matrix we denote $R$, followed by the translation $x \mapsto x + d$.  That is, the full transformation (in standard coordinates) is given by $T(x) = Rx + d$.

Let $J$ denote the $90^\circ$ rotation about the same axis as $R$. Note that $R$ can be written in the form $R = \cos \theta I + \sin \theta J$, where $I$ denotes the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Its "square root" can be written in the form $S = \cos (\theta/2)I + \sin (\theta/2)J$. It is easy to see that $S$ should be the rotational component of our "halfway" transformation.

Note that if we are given the transformation matrix $R$, then the angle satisfies $$
\operatorname{trace}(R) = 1 + 2 \cos \theta,
$$
which allows us to compute $\cos \theta, \sin \theta,$ and $J$ from the matrix $R$.

We will describe the halfway transformation as $H(x) = Sx + e$, and we wish to solve for the vector $e$.  We must select $e$ such that $T(x) = H(H(x))$. That is,
$$
Rx + d = S(Sx + e) + e = S^2x + Se + e = Rx + (I + S)e.
$$
In other words, we must select $e$ such that $(I+S)e = d$. That is, it suffices to take $e = (I + S)^{-1}d$, where we note that $(I + S)$ must be invertible because it is a rotation by $\theta/2$, which is not a multiple of $180^\circ$ (so there is no $x$ for which $Sx = -x \implies (I + S)x = 0$).

---

We can go a step further an compute this inverse explicitly.  We have
$$
(I + S)^{-1} = ((1 + \cos (\theta/2))I + \sin(\theta/2)J)^{-1}.
$$
It turns out that because we have $J^2 = -I$, we can treat these coefficients as the real and complex parts of a complex number. So, following the process by which one would compute $(a + bi)^{-1}$, we find that
$$
(I + S)^{-1} = \frac{1}{(1 + \cos(\theta/2))^2 + \sin^2(\theta/2)}((1 + \cos (\theta/2))I - \sin(\theta/2)J)
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2 + 2 \cos (\theta/2)}((1 + \cos (\theta/2))I - \sin(\theta/2)J),
$$
which is to say that we have
$$
e = \frac{1}{2 + 2 \cos (\theta/2)}((1 + \cos (\theta/2))I - \sin(\theta/2)J)d.
$$

Comment: By any chance, is there any code that implements this ?

Comment: Not that I know of